# how to execute a mysql query inside a while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with mysql connection i want to execute a query inside a while of mysqli_fetch_assoc but, i am getting error like "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

```
<?php
    $sql = "call sp_getUpline('$user_id')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

    if($numrow > 1)
    {
        while($resultArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $parent_id = $resultArray['parent_id'];
            if($parent_id != null)
            {
                $Level = $resultArray['Level'] + 1; 

                $comp_sql = "SELECT * FROM user_comp_plan where id='$parent_id'";
                $comp_result = mysqli_query($connection, $comp_sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); //getting error here

          }

        }
    }

?>
```

**UPDATE**

I stored the result in array but, still getting the same problem.

```
<?php
        $sql = "call sp_getUpline('$user_id')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        echo $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($result);    

        if($numrow > 1)
        {
            $data = array();
            while($resultArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $data[] = $resultArray;
            }
            for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){       
                $parent_id = $data[$i]['parent_id'];
                if($parent_id != null)
                {
                    $Level = $data[$i]['Level'] + 1; 

                    $comp_sql = "SELECT * FROM user_comp_plan where id='$parent_id'";
                    $comp_result = mysqli_query($connection, $comp_sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); //getting error here

                }

            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Try this $comp_sql = "SELECT  comp_plan_type FROM user_comp_plan where id='$parent_id'"; hope this helps.

Comment: Thats not an issue its just typo problem. Once check my update

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two simultaneous queries because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default. 
You can either fetch the first one into an array and loop through that, or tell mysqli to buffer the queries using mysqli::store_result